# Dynamically nesting React.js components

Tags: reactjs

I'd like to create a **flexible/dynamic** JSX form format that can be rendered using React.js. This format has to include nested groups. A group can contain other groups as well as questions.

```jsx
var Group = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <fieldset></fieldset>
        );
    }
});

var Text = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <label>
               <input type="text"/>
           </label>
        );
     }
});

React.render(
    <form>
        <Group>
           <Text/>
        </Group>
        <Text/>
    </form>,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

I want to produce:

```jsx
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <label>
            <input type="text">
        </label>
    </fieldset>
    <label>
        <input type="text">
    </label>
</form>
```

However the `<fieldset>` element is not populated. The output just contains an empty `<fieldset>`.

How should I nest react.js components, and still maintain the flexibility of re-using question and group components at root and nested levels?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

When you nest React elements into other React elements in JSX, the parent element gets passed a `children` prop that contains the children elements. See [Type of the Children props](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/children-props-type.html).

Another way to look at it is that `<Group><div></div></Group>` is the JSX equivalent to `React.createElement(Group, null, React.createElement('div', null))`, which is in turn equivalent to `React.createElement(Group, {children: React.createElement('div', null)})`.

So in your case, your Group component would look like:

```jsx
var Group = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <fieldset>{this.props.children}</fieldset>
        );
    }
});
```

Note that the children props is an opaque data structure (it might be a single element or an array of elements depending on the input), so if you ever need to manipulate it, you should use the [`React.Children`](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.children) API.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone else is having trouble debugging through this as well and just in case the top-voted answer doesn't work for them, the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html) say that `User defined components must be capitalized.`
So in your case, if you import your `fieldset` controller as `Fieldset` instead, everything should work just fine.