# How to style one react component inside another?

Tags: css, reactjs, styles

I'm new to css and I can't figure out how to position one component inside another in React. I can show them separately, but when I put one inside another. I don't see the one inside. I think the problem is in the css file

```
#homePage{
   section{
      h1{
        text-align: left; //this is shown
      }
      //here I want to add the other React component but I don't know how

   }
}
```

And the render method:

```
<div id="homePage">
  <Component1>
    <section>
     <h1>Hi</h1>
     <Component2>
     </Component2>
    </section>
  </Component1>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, is the question about applying styles to the  the nested components in react  ? or is it about placing some  components inside another component?

Comment: It is just one component inside another

Comment: Please post some more code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i understand , you could have the className attribute defined inside your  Component2's HTML tags.

```
class Component2 extends Component{ 

render(){

    return(
        <section className="component2styles">
            This is Component2
        </section >
    );
} }
```

Now , you can change ur style sheet as

```
#homePage{
   section{
      h1{
        text-align: left; //this is shown
      }
      //components2 style will be nested here

     section.component2styles{
       border:1px solid blue;
     }

   }
}
```

Or as an alternative you can try inline-styles , seems to be gaining a lot of traction in React development.

```
render(){
 var styleobj={color:'red'};
 return( <section style={styleobj} > This is Component 2 </section> ) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add some class/id to your Component2 like `<Component2 className="my-specific-class" />` to style it?

(btw, I hope your css is less/sass one to allow nested styles like you did)

**EDIT**
By adding className attr. to your Component2, I mean adding it in Component2 render method like

```
render: function() {
    return (
        <div id="your-id" className="your-class">
            some html here
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Yes it is a sass. No I didn't add a id or className. But when I try to add it it says className doesn't exist. Should I add it as a props in component2 ? p.s. I'm new to all of this

Comment: Yep my example wasn't complete. If you Component2 render method return something like `<div>some html here</div>`, you should add the className attribute like `<div id="..." className="...">some html here</div>` (I'll edit my answer to avoid future misunderstanding :) !)

Comment: Yes I do, but my question is should I and how can I add this component inside #homePage. Thanks

Comment: Could your copy/paste your React code and/or the rendered html?

Comment: A thing that could be wrong with your code is the way you do the nested components. I'm trying to avoid that on my side (and I don't see your whole code so maybe it's not the case), but have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29020863/dynamically-nesting-react-js-components

Comment: I'll try to make a jsfiddle this afternoon if I got some time

Comment: Seems like you're fine with @Luciferous response, so don't need a jsfiddle anymore I guess :)